# How to search value in Dataset<Row> in java spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark

My Dataset< Row > (java spark) input is :

| Heros | Powers | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Superman | Invisible | 1 |
| Batman | Strength | 2 |
| SpiderMan | Strong | 3 |

By knowing the name of my heros, i would like to retrieve the rank.
For exemple for Superman, i would like to have the return 1, not all the line but just the value.
I don't know how to do by using a spark dataset. Thank for your help !

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
int rank = dataset.filter("Heros ='Superman'").select(col("Rank")).first().getInt(0);
```